# What is the meaning of this line in Candida by Shaw?

Tags: george-bernard-shaw, candida

In *Candida* by Shaw, there is this line by Morell at the beginning. (Fourth speech from the beginning)

> Morell: **Just like Anarchists not to know that they can't have a 
>   parson on Sunday!** Tell them to come to church if they want to 
>   hear me: it will do them good. Say I can only come on Mondays and 
>   Thursdays. Have you the diary there?

I cannot understand the meaning of the bold part in this line. Can someone please explain what it means. I have looked up the internet but could not find any help.

Comment: Perhaps because Anarchists often aren't religious and therefore aren't knowledgeable about the practice and customs of the church?

Comment: What exactly did you look up on the internet?

Comment: @Spagirl, line by line explanation of Candida.

Comment: As Rand al'Thor points out, the nature of Anarchism is key. Did you look that up?

Comment: @Spagirl, I knew the meaning of anarchist but could not relate that to what is being  said after in the speech by Morell. Now i somewhat understand. "Anarchists" here is associated with atheists. Right?

Comment: @MrAP https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchism_and_religion I'm not trying to be difficult, just trying to encourage you to look at the problem in a more creative way than googling for info on a specific line of dialogue. There was no reason to suppose the relationship between anarchists and ministers was exclusive to the work, so a wider search would have helped you work out the answer.

Comment: @Spagirl Please turn that into an answer! :-) I found this question on the Unanswered list, which is frustrating when it's essentially been solved in comments.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I essentially told them to google it and gave some hint on how to approach any search. I've been told on this stack specifically that that doesn't equal an answer. Your comment  was closer to an answer and gave more actual information than mine did. :)

Comment: @Spagirl I *could* post an answer, but I've got so many answers on this site already. Your Wikipedia link has more information with more citations than anything in my comment - there must be a few sentences from there which you could quote to make a decent answer (*and* put your general advice on searching for answers like this into a place where it can be upvoted). It looks like the OP is still around on SE, and I'm sure they'd appreciate having their question answered properly (as well as getting another knocked off our Unanswered list).

Comment: @Randal'Thor TBH I'm regarding myself as being on hiatus for this stack until I get a better feel for where the balance is between Comments and Answers. The last 1/2 dozen or so contacts I've had here have essentially been to tell me I'm getting it wrong, which feels odd after a year of no previous probs on different stacks. Not feeling wildly well suited to SE-Lit right now.

Comment: @Spagirl Awww :-( Sorry if my comments came off as telling you you're getting it wrong; I didn't mean to be rude. It's just that Lit has so many unanswered questions, and not enough high-rep users, so I'll take any opportunity to encourage other people to post good answers - especially when they already have the makings of one in comments! There's nothing wrong with commenting as you did, but by posting an answer you'd be able to earn rep for it, plus enable this question to be marked as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Since Spagirl didn't want to post an answer, I'm going ahead and writing one.</sup>

### Anarchists are generally non-religious and frequently anti-religious.

You can read more about anarchism and religion [on Wikipedia (with many references)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchism_and_religion), but this is the essential point: that anarchists are typically opposed to religion. This would explain why they don't know the details of how religion works, which is what the Reverend Morell is complaining about:

> PROSERPINE. Another lecture?
>
> MORELL. Yes. The Hoxton Freedom Group want me to address them on Sunday morning (great emphasis on "Sunday," this being the unreasonable part of the business). What are they?
>
> PROSERPINE. Communist Anarchists, I think.
>
> MORELL. Just like Anarchists not to know that they can't have a parson on Sunday! Tell them to come to church if they want to hear me: it will do them good. Say I can only come on Mondays and Thursdays.

The Reverend Morell engages himself to give lectures to a great many groups and organisations, but only on Mondays and Thursdays. On Sundays he is in church, not on call for giving lectures elsewhere. He seems quite put out that people might not know this, but from anarchists it's less surprising.